# D3JS certain date intervals crash Firefox on MacOS

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, jsfiddle, macos-sierra

I have a strange issue when using certain intervals with D3 and Firefox
The code runs fine in Safari and Chrome

Heres a test
https://jsfiddle.net/andytela/gdsx8fug/4/
that crashes Firefox

Yet if I delete the last 4 lines of the data:

```
Mild,2050-01-01,1066.00
Moderate,2050-01-01,656.00
Severe,2050-01-01,293.00
Total,2050-01-01,2014.00
```

Then it works fine, yet if I take out the first 4 lines then it doesn't work. It seems to not like the future dates. Yet if I take the first 8 lines, then it works, which seems to contradict this

The error seems to be occurring in the "interval.range" function, but I can't seem to narrow down the cause

The error I get is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdDb4.png) "unresponsive script" using Firefox 51.0.1 on MacOS
Also tried on other versions of Firefox and get the same issue

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: It's running OK to me on Firefox.

Comment: Working fine with Firefox 52.0 and ubuntu

Comment: @gerardo-furtado just checked on a PC and can see it's working so have just added a note about MacOS